# Bootstrap Modal Confirm Delete with Dynamic title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to have multiple delete buttons, and have the modal body change based on the button. Instead of the body saying "Are you sure?" I want  it to say "Are you sure you want to delete row 5?" or row 4?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3ddq/1/)

```
<form action ="#" method="POST"><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete" data-title="row 5"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add some kind of generic selector for your buttons and a proper identification (value, id, etc).

Then you could easily retrieve the button identification in your javascript and change the modal body before showing it.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxv5dr93/).

HTML:

```
<form action ="#" method="POST">
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>

<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels1" value="delete1"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> row 1</button>    
</form>

<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('button.btn-danger').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(this).attr("value")=='delete')
        $('#confirm .modal-body').html('Are you sure?');
    else
        $('#confirm .modal-body').html('Are you sure you want to delete row 1?');

    var $form=$(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
            $form.trigger('submit');
        });
});
```